# How to add all numbers in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to get that number of settlements.

but it's not working.

what's wrong with this code?

Where should i edit this code?

I expected result : 
total value : 2614

but result of total is 0.

**casperjs code is.**

```
var test = 0;
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;

var casper = require('casper').create({
    // verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    // clientScripts: ["/vendor/jquery.min.js"],
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: true,
        encoding: 'utf8',
        colorizerType: 'Dummy',
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
    }
});


casper.start();

casper.then(function() {
  casper.thenOpen('https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs', function(){
      msg = 'phantomjs : ' + (this.fetchText('#js-repo-pjax-container > div.container.new-discussion-timeline.experiment-repo-nav > div.repository-content > div.overall-summary.overall-summary-bottomless > div > div > ul > li.commits > a > span', true));
      num1 = parseInt(msg.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')); // result : 390
  });

  casper.thenOpen('https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs', function(){
      msg = 'github : ' + (this.fetchText('#js-repo-pjax-container > div.container.new-discussion-timeline.experiment-repo-nav > div.repository-content > div.overall-summary.overall-summary-bottomless > div > div > ul > li.commits > a > span', true));
      num2 = parseInt(msg.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')); // result : 2224
  });

  total = num1 + num2;
  // 390 + 2224 = 2614
  this.echo('total : ' + total);
  // but result is 0
});
```

casper.run();

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: I expected result : total value : 2614

but result of total is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statement is evaluated before opening of pages. You need to wrap your it into step with `.then` and it will work.

```
casper.then(function() {
    total = num1 + num2;
    // 390 + 2224 = 2614
    this.echo('total : ' + total);
    // but result is 0
})
```